# NERDTree: when you have a split, pressing enter will open the file in which split?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

So I am confused by what's the proper behavior of NERDTree

When I go to NERDTree and press `'s'`, a split happens on the RIGHT side of the screen (I have `splitright` enabled).

Now if I go back to the NERDTree split and press `enter` on another file, the LEFT split gets replaced.

I would like all opening of files to happen on the right split. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: On my installation, `enter` places the file in the last used split. So, if my cursor is in the left split and I move it to NERDTree, and then press `enter`, NERDTree will open the file in the left split.

Comment: It might be that OP is moving to NERDTree by `Ctrl-W h` instead of using `:NERDTree` or an equivalent mapping, always passing through left split... I have NERDTree mapped to `F2` and `NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1`, so I never use window navigation to get to it, and always get the file in my current split.

Comment: @Amadan Yes that's exactly it. I navigate to NERDTree by going 'left', which is :wincmd h<CR>. If NERDTree opens in the last split then I guess the correct behavior will always open on the left split since I have to go through the left split to get to the NERDTree panel.

Comment: This reminds me of an opinion piece I read the other day: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/).